# Change ValidationGroup of RadButton on RadTabStrip Tab Selection in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, tabs

I having a problem while changing the ValidationGroup of RadButton on RadTabStrip Tab Selection in asp.net.

I have a form which having Header and Details part. On button click, header part data will be saved and after that the details part data will be saved. In details I have 14 tabs in which some tabs having Grid structure and some tabs having form structure. After saving header data, what I want to do is that once I click on any tab, then in that tab the form controls and RequiredFieldValidator should work once clicked on button.

Need the solution at clientSide or Server side code.

Folks, please guide me how to resolve this issue as I am not getting any idea to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ValidationGroup` on each tab to something unique, then on the client side, you can change the validation group of the button, by:

```
$find("myBtn").set_validationGroup("myValidationGroup");
```

You would apply this when changing tabs, for example.